# How can I delete single values in a row by condition in R?

Tags: r

Assume I have following matrix:

```
      2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2022-01-01 2022-06-06 2022-09-01 2025-01-0
[1,]       -100          0         10          0         10        120
[2,]       -200          0         30         20          0        130
[3,]       -250         20          0          0          0        280
...
```

Now I would like to store rows by certain conditions. 
For example I would like to store the first row without zeros and the 2nd row without values below zero or zero:

```
c(-100,10,10,120)    #Row 1 
 -100   10   10  120
c(30,20,130)         #Row 2
 30  20 130
```

How can I do that? 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your matrix is:

```
mat = cbind(c(-100,-200,-250),c(0,0,20),
c(10,30,0),c(0,20,0),c(10,0,0),c(120,130,280))
```

Then you get a list:

```
store_vals = apply(mat,1,function(i)i[i!=0])
```

Each element corresponds to each row, if you want to store row1 as a vector:

```
row1 = store_vals[[1]]
row1
[1] -100   10   10  120
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late to this one, but here is another solution that will work with `data.frame`s and matrices, and will accept any generic selection condition to filter out values with. The selection itself is done by evaluating `eval(parse(value, selection_condition))`, and then filtering out all those that evaluate to `TRUE`. Then to cycle through the rows (of say, a `data.frame`), this function (`selcol()`) can be called from within a `for loop`, and its results stored in a list as demonstrated below:

```
#----

#Function to select columns based on arbitrary condition(s)
selcols <- function(myinp, mycond){

  #In theory, the user can pass whatever
  #equivalency conditions they want
  #This is just some (un)necessary checking
  #that has been commented out
  #if( grepl("^[\\-]{0,1}[0-9]+", mycond, perl = TRUE) ){
  #  mycond <- paste0("== ", mycond)
  #} else if( grepl("^>[=]*[0-9]+|^<[=]*[0-9]+", mycond, perl = TRUE) ){
  #  mycond <- mycond
  #} else{
  #  stop("Unable to parse selection condition! Check the input!")
  #}

  #Parse the equivalency conditions
  #and assign NAs accordingly
  myout <- unlist(
    lapply(as.vector(myinp), 
           function(x){
             ifelse(eval(parse(text = paste0(x, mycond))), NA, x)}))

  #Return vector of values excluding the NAs
  return(myout[!is.na(myout)])

}

#----

#----

#Your data

df <- "      2020-01-01 2021-01-01 2022-01-01 2022-06-06 2022-09-01 2025-01-0
[1,]       -100          0         10          0         10        120
[2,]       -200          0         30         20          0        130
[3,]       -250         20          0          0          0        280"

df <- as.matrix(read.table(text = df))

#----

#Example runs

#Filter out all zeroes
myl <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
 myl[[i]] <- selcols(df[i, ], "==0")
}

myl[[1]]
# [1] -100   10   10  120

#Filter out all values less than 0
myl <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  myl[[i]] <- selcols(df[i, ], "<0")
}

myl[[1]]
# [1]   0  10   0  10 120

#----
```